# templating: removing the elements that doesn't have the data

Tags: java, groovy, template-engine

I am using the Groovy's xml templating feature. Below is my template and binding(s). Some times I doesn't have any value for the LastName. I would like groovy to not create the element if it doesn't have non-empty data. Can someone suggest how to do it?

**Template**

```
<PersonName nameIdentifier="Current">
     <FirstName>${FirstName}</FirstName>
     <LastName>${LastName}</LastName>
</PersonName>
```

**Binding**

```
def binding1 = ['FirstName':FirstName ,'LastName':'LastName']
def binding2 = ['FirstName':FirstName ,'LastName':'']
```

**Code**

```
public static String createXml(String templateResourceName, def bindings)
    {
        def engine = new XmlTemplateEngine()
        def output = engine.createTemplate(getResource(templateResourceName)).make(bindings)

        return output.toString()
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can work:

`<% print LastName != null ? "<LastName>"+LastName+"</LastName>" : "" %>`

But this is the 1st time I heard of this feature, so if it does it will be a lucky guess ...

**Edit:** Tried it out a bit on the Groovy web console - this should work:

`def text = '<PersonName nameIdentifier="Current">\n<FirstName>${FirstName}</FirstName>\n<% print LastName != "" ? "<LastName>"+LastName+"</LastName>\\n" : "" %></PersonName>'`

Comment: +1 this works with the example given (empty string or null) `<% print( !LastName ? '' : "<LastName>${LastName}</LastName>" ) %>`

Comment: I tried this but is failing with [XmlTemplateEngine] the below error java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing XML source failed.
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1231)
 at groovy.util.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:175)
 at groovy.text.XmlTemplateEngine.createTemplate(XmlTemplateEngine.java:295)
 ... 3 more

Comment: this worked if I use SimpleTemplateEngine instead of XmlTemplateEngine